# bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Unexpected token

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

In BigQuery my projectID is "restaurant-chatb-1581323614778". When I code this in Apps Script:

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectID, jobConfig);
(where projectID is as shown above and jobConfig is shown below), I get an error message:
**GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Unexpected token. restaurant-chatb-158**

The projectId appears to be cut off in the error message. How can I solve this?

I tried this:
var query = `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM \`${projectId}.${datasetId}.${tableId}\` WHERE restaurantName = @restaurantName AND city = @city AND state = @state`;
var queryParameters = [
{ name: 'restaurantName', parameterType: { type: 'STRING' }, parameterValue: { value: restaurantName } },
{ name: 'city', parameterType: { type: 'STRING' }, parameterValue: { value: city } },
{ name: 'state', parameterType: { type: 'STRING' }, parameterValue: { value: state } }
];

var jobConfig = {
query: {
query: query,
useLegacySql: false,
parameterMode: 'NAMED',
queryParameters: queryParameters
}
};

The error refers to:
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(projectID, jobConfig);

Comment: Please learn how to [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)